# How to make m by n matrix with all elements int x using ArrayList?

Tags: java, matrix, arraylist, generic-collections

Making m by n matrix using `ArrayList` in Java. I'm trying to make a constructor with the function of making m by n matrix with all elements 'int x'.

I've declared matrix `ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> matrix = new ArrayList<>();`

The class name is `MatrixImpl` so the type of constructor I'm trying to make is

`public MatrixImpl(double x, int m, int n){..}`

And also, I can't use 2D Array in this project.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
class MatrixImpl {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> matrix = new ArrayList<>();
        MatrixImpl(double x, int m, int n){
}
```

Expected result : m by n matrix with all elements 'x'.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. `ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> matrix = new ArrayList<>();` is enough, the matrix will grow dynamically as you add elements. If you really need to initialize it with the specified size, use the constructor which accepts the size and add a `n` new array lists into the outer list.

Comment: It's not clear what the actual issue is; you know the sizes, you just need to initialize the lists.

Comment: As you have m x n matrix you don't need an `ArrayList` that allows dynamic sizes, arrays will suffice, e.g.:  `double[][] matrix = new double[m][n];`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a temp arrayList and put values and added to arraylist to matrix arrayList. repeat that process for no of rows

```
MatrixImpl(double x, int m, int n){
ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> matrix = new ArrayList<>();
        for( int i = 0;i<m;i++){
           ArrayList<Double> t = new ArrayList<>();
           for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
               t.add(x);
            }
            matrix.add(t);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

java.util.Arrays has some convenience fill methods for primitive types.
Ans as suggested in the comments a 2-dimensional array is good enough since you know the size of your matrix at construction time.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MatrixImpl {

    double matrix[][];

    public MatrixImpl (double x, int m, int n)
    {
        matrix=new double[m][n];
        for (int i=0;i<m;i++)
            Arrays.fill(matrix[i],x);
    }
    public void print()
    {
        for (int i=0;i<matrix.length;i++)
        {
            for (int j=0;j<matrix[i].length;j++)
                System.out.print(" "+matrix[i][j]);
            System.out.println();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MatrixImpl mi=new MatrixImpl(5,4,3);
        mi.print();
    }

}
```